# Is there a quantifiable benefit for comparing to zero if negative numbers are not a factor?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators

Assuming that negative numbers are not a factor; is there a clear, quantifiable benefit (such as a performance difference) for comparing zero using the greater than or equal to operators?

**For example, compare the two IF statements below:**

```
if (x > 0) {
   functionOne();
} else {
   functionTwo();
}

if (x == 0) {
   functionTwo();
} else {
   functionOne();
}
```

Comment: `>` or `==` comparing with zero will be always faster than non-zero value.

Comment: With such a simple case, unless you are doing millions of comparisons of this type per second (and even then I doubt it), both ways are the same performance-wise

Comment: You should express what you really expect it to do, not what gives negligible performance benefits. Maybe even go for `if (x == 0) …; else if (x > 0) …;`

Comment: you should be using `x === 0`

Comment: As a proof, test [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffntuytp/). You'll see how little the difference is (when any), and how sometimes the first one is faster and how sometimes the second one is faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not meaningfully different. In [billions of runs of each version, the speed difference is negligible (link to jsPerf demo)](http://jsperf.com/if-operator-speed).

Results from a sample run:

```
x    operator   ops/sec
1    ==         1,899,677,783
0    ==         1,896,694,559
1    >          1,886,826,964
0    >          1,893,169,247
```

Those are simply not meaningful differences.